# Best way to fork/copy a VB.NET solution using VS2010

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, fork

Is there a straightforward way to make a copy of a VB.NET solution and continue the project in another direction?

I'd think this is a common problem but haven't been able to find an easy solution. Copying the files and renaming seems messy to me.

Does the VS IDE provide anything like this?

**Update**: It's a small project on my home computer so I'm currently not using source control. I wasn't expecting to need to fork or anything. Is there a way I can do this without setting up git or similar?

Comment: If not using SCM, perhaps the best way is to save the project as a template (File > Export Template...)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO this is an SCM (source control management) question, not an editor (VS IDE) question.

Why is copying and renaming messy?  That's eventually what has to happen anyway.  You don't mention which SCM you're using, but if it's SVN/Tortoise, if you rename the project file you'll get a dialog asking you if you want to rename other files similarly named.  (e.g. the .filters files)  That makes it go easier.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look at a source control package to accomplish this. [git](http://git-scm.com/) is an excellent option for this type of thing because of the ease of branching and merging--or more simply, saving a particular "state" of your solution and then continuing in another direction. There's also a nice Visual Studio integration option for git called [Git Source Control Provider](https://github.com/yysun/Git-Source-Control-Provider).

Comment: I've updated the question, I havent set up git since it's a small home project (perhaps I should have).